# Unable to Convert DT_STR to DT_i8 in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, expression, data-conversion

I am Loading data from a file, which has input datatype for one of the column is String (DT_STR) and my Target data type in Bigint which is DT_I8. I tried Data conversion task to convert it but throws an error and I tried expression "DT_I8(Column_Name)" but it failed. Can some help me with the expression that i can use to convert this.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: What does the source data look like? My guesses are leading/trailing whitespace or NULLs being at fault here but we need more information that what is provided.